# FDR4.2.7 could not connect license server

Tags: fdr

I need to use FDR4 for my papers，but when I download FDR4.2.7, I find I could not connet to the licensing servers.
I also see the FDR release note:
Release Notes
4.2.7 (11/05/2020)
Fixes an additional issue that meant FDR4 could not connect to the licensing servers.
4.2.6 (10/05/2020)
Fixes an issue that meant FDR4 could not connect to the licensing servers.

I use Ubuntu 16.04 TLS, could someone send me FDR version 4.2.5 OR other version that could run the demo: " casper-2.1\ExamplesLibrary\Algebra\dh.csp"，I also have FDR2 which could not run this demo.

Thank you very much.